# How hard/possible it is for an engineer to make this happen?

Tags: power-supply

I need to get one of these power supplies to use it in something I'm developing. The problem is that where I live there are no shops that sell this.

What I need is this:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, this is a power supply with a special form factor. This is exactly the form factor I need for my project.

However, like I said, no one sells it here, so I need to fabricate it from scratch.

Do you think this is a viable project for an Electronics Engineer?

I wonder maybe these power supplies are manufactured by machines and it is impossible/tricky for a someone to do it.

Edited: a PS of 12v and 2A will do.

Comment: Best option is to buy online and import it.

Comment: How many pieces you need?

Comment: @Brian the problem is, here where I live (Argentina) we are having troubles with it. 
Kamil if everything goes well, a lot.

Comment: Any reason you need an internal supply instead of a power brick?

Comment: I'm designing and building a backlit picture frame, and it looks ugly if you have an external power supply, also if someone wants to completely cover the power outlet, with a power brick that's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well they are manufactured by machines, but prototypes or even small production lots could be put together by hand.

A competent power supply engineer with experience in offline converters could design a custom converter for you, but then there are a bunch of regulatory requirements and tests that you have to do which may vary from country to country.  So it can get expensive depending on which and how many countries you want to sell it in.  Certainly possible though.

Any way of procuring an already built and tested supply is likely to be cheaper, even if it means flying to wherever they are built to make some sort of import deal.

Answer (score 2):

The least expensive option (for time and money) is to import it.

The term 'engineer' is incredibly broad. I'll assume you mean an electrical engineer or electronics engineer.

Of course, the picture power supply was designed by engineers, so an engineer can design another one. And though it was likely assembled at least partially by a machine, a skilled person could easily assemble one.

If you can buy the components, design schematic (or copy a reference), and design a PCB then you can certainly create the same form factor on your own.

I would start by defining your input power requirements. Your output appears to be 12V at 2A. From there you can find a power supply IC from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/powermanagement/power_portal.page) or another company, use their reference design, and layout your PCB in the exact form factor you need.

Comment: Yes, an electronic engineer. I would provide the circuit with 220v.

Comment: Excellent. An electronic engineer should be able to figure this out without too much trouble. Note that I'm speaking about prototypes, John D touches on regulatory issues which I completely neglected, my answer is the same but the first sentence may be even more relevant if you're planning to produce and sell small quantities of your something-you-are-developing.

Comment: Where can I find reference models?, is there a list or something like that?. Maybe, just maybe, if the design is already made, I can build it myself.

Comment: There are thousands of lists. It's worth noting that there are lots of ways to do this. There are many variables in a problem like this, which is why engineers exist, to design the solution. I don't know what your experience is, or if you're the electronic engineer you spoke of, but you can start by Googling '220vac to 12vdc'. Then you can find some basic schematics for transformer->rectifier->filter->(LDO or DC-DC Buck regulator) topologies. Then you just need to select the components. Or get a reference design from a TI development board for one of their parts.

Comment: No I'm not the engineer, but maybe with some assistance and work it can be done.